# How to override refresh action in PagingToolbar

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I need to write some action based on the refresh button in the Paging toolbar. How can I override the `doRefresh()` method?

```
this.bbar=Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
      store: store,
      displayInfo: true,
      displayMsg: 'Displaying records {0} - {1} of {2}',
      emptyMsg: "No topics to display" 
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you just want to do is once use

```
Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
      store: store,
      displayInfo: true,
      displayMsg: 'Displaying records {0} - {1} of {2}',
      emptyMsg: "No topics to display",
      doRefresh : function(){
         // Keep or remove these code
         var me = this,
             current = me.store.currentPage;

         if (me.fireEvent('beforechange', me, current) !== false) {
             me.store.loadPage(current);
         }
      }
});
```

or for all pagebars.

```
Ext.PagingToolbar.prototype.doRefresh = function() {
     // Keep or remove these code
     var me = this,
         current = me.store.currentPage;

     if (me.fireEvent('beforechange', me, current) !== false) {
         me.store.loadPage(current);
     }
}
```

**Note that if you doing so you have to double check it each time you update the EXTJS core to ensure functionality!**

Comment: thnx, exactly fullfill my requirements.

Comment: @ZakariaImtiaz You're welcome :) You should accept the correct answer with the check below the vote-number ;)

Comment: @ZakariaImtiaz lol It is always good to take care about that and more important it is a help for all other users that stumple over your Question to figure out what was the solution. But anyway thanks for accepting

Comment: well. i was trying to get first row of my grid selected after refreshing. for this it was needed. finally i override refresh method as you suggested and put my necessary code after this [me.store.loadPage(current);] line.

Answer (score 5):

```
Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
  store: store,
  displayInfo: true,
  displayMsg: 'Displaying records {0} - {1} of {2}',
  emptyMsg: "No topics to display",
  doRefresh : function(){
     var me = this,
         current = me.store.currentPage;

     if (me.fireEvent('beforechange', me, current) !== false) {
        me.store.loadPage(1, {                                      
            callback: function (records, operation, success) {  
                Ext.getCmp('educationGrid').getSelection(records, operation, success);                                      
            }
        });
     }
  }
```

});

...................................

```
getSelection: function(records, operation, success){
    var grid= Ext.getCmp('educationGrid'); //my grid
    grid.getView().select(0);
}
```